# How should an ASP.NET Core custom InputFormatter/ReadRequestBodyAsync return to indicate error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**TL;DR**

If my `Content-Type "application/x-ourformat"` bound custom `TextInputFormatter` cannot parse the input, I want to return HTTP `400` (possibly [`415`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415)) back to the client.

What is the correct way to return from the implementation of `ReadRequestBodyAsync` to get the framework to return a `4xx` HTTP response?

---

We have a custom formatter for `application/x-ourformat` built upon the [`TextInputFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2) as explained in the link.

The example from the MS docs above does error handling as follows:

[ReadRequestBodyAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.inputformatter.readrequestbodyasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

```
public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(
        InputFormatterContext context, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
{
    ...
    return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(contact);
        }
        catch
        {
            logger.LogError("Read failed: nameLine = {nameLine}", nameLine);
            return await InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync();
        }
    }
```

That is, if the processing of the input fails with an exception, it will return `FailureAsync()`.

**However**, this will NOT result in a HTTP 400 response, instead the input object bound to the Api will simply be `null`.

What *does* result in a 400 response is:

- Throwing an exception out of `ReadRequestBodyAsync`
- Setting `context.ModelState.AddModelError("My Key", "Couldn't really understand you.");` prior to returning `FailureAsync`.

But I do neither understand which one is "correct" nor do I really understand what the ModelError is supposed to represent.

Comment: I wouldn’t throw an exception as catching exceptions is expensive. This may be detrimental to server performance if you receive lots of malformed requests. A model error represents that the model itself (when key=string.Empty) or a property (where key is the name/path of the invalid property) doesn’t satisfy a constraint or contains malformed data. Therefore, it kinda applies in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now dug into the call chain for `ReadRequestBodyAsync`:

Eventually the result will be processed in [`BindModelAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v2.2.13/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/BodyModelBinder.cs#L158), which:

- On HasError, Logs, and returns nothing, stating `// Formatter encountered an error. Do not use the model it returned.`
- On exception, does `ModelState.AddModelError(modelBindingKey, exception`

So, since the framework itself will set a ModelError on an exception, it sure seems at least that setting the ModelError oneself is more useful.

Like [ckuri noted above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74392428/how-should-an-asp-net-core-custom-inputformatter-readrequestbodyasync-return-to#comment131331380_74392428) :

> A model error represents that the model ... doesn’t satisfy a
> constraint or contains malformed data. Therefore, it kinda applies in
> your case.

Answer (score -1):

Below is a sample response.  Notice the 200 OK is before the http headers.  The HTTP headers have a key and a value separated by a colon.  The body is after the headers.  the content length is the number of bytes in the body.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2009 12:28:53 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Jul 2009 19:15:56 GMT
ETag: "34aa387-d-1568eb00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 51
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/plain
Hello World! My content includes a trailing CRLF.
```

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question? (tagged C#)

Comment: Everything!!!  Op needs to understand what a response looks like.   The status is not in the body,  An error response the body usually is null.

Comment: The question is about the correct C# code. The question does not ask about the body of the *response*. It asks about the response *header* when the *request* body is malformed., and how to correctly react to that in the context of the framework code.  Your answer does not help the OP.

Comment: The question is why the op is getting an exception when getting a bad response. To understand why the exception is occurring you have to understand the format of the response.  The OP asked how to send a correct response.

Comment: No, the question is "What is the correct way to return from the implementation of ReadRequestBodyAsync to get (the framework to return) a 4xx HTTP response?" Nowhere in the question is it stated "why the exception is occuring".